# My JavaScript accordion is not toggling properly. I need the content to hide when I click on its title panel

Tags: javascript, accordion

I created a Java Script code that creates an accordion. The way it is working right now is that when you click on a closed content title panel the content will show, but when I click on the open content's title panel it doesn't close it. So it opens the other panels but can't close the current open content.

I have tried different else is statements targeting different Java Script elements but all lead me to the same result.

```
function addClass(el, klass) {
    el.classList.add(klass);
}

function removeClass(el, klass) {
    el.classList.remove(klass);
}

const accordionItems = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item");
const accordionContentPanes = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-content");

// Hide each besides target accordion on click
accordionItems.forEach(function(accordion) {
    // Clicked accordions clickable target
    const accordionTitleRow = accordion.firstElementChild;
    console.log(accordion);

    accordionTitleRow.addEventListener("click", toggleAccordion);
});

function toggleAccordion(e) {

    accordionContentPanes.forEach(function(content) {

        console.log(content); 

        // Check if clicked row matches the content's previous element sibling
        if (content.previousElementSibling === e.target) {
            removeClass(content, "hidden");
            addClass(content.parentElement, "active");

        }   
        else {
            removeClass(content.parentElement, "active");
            addClass(content, 'hidden');

        }        
    });
}
```

The final result is what I already have plus the functionality I explained above.

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="accordion-item overflow-hidden w-full">
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2; border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;;" class="accordion-title-row flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer 
px-6 py-4 headerItem" id="first">
        <div class="flex">
            <i style=" font-size: 1.75em;margin-right: .5em;" class="fas fa-car fa-3x grey-text overlay"></i>
            <h2 style="padding-top: .15em;" class="font-bold text-lg mb-0">Automotive</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <svg style="color: #2196f3;" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" height="20" class="fill-current text-grey-dark accordion-arrow">
                <title>cheveron down</title>
                <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="automotive" class="accordion-content list-reset leading-normal px-8 py-4 hidden">
        Here is some content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item overflow-hidden w-full">
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2; border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;;" class="accordion-title-row flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer 
px-6 py-4 headerItem" id="second">
        <div class="flex">
            <i style=" font-size: 1.75em;margin-right: .5em;" class="fas fa-car fa-3x grey-text overlay"></i>
            <h2 style="padding-top: .15em;" class="font-bold text-lg mb-0">Other</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <svg style="color: #2196f3;" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" height="20" class="fill-current text-grey-dark accordion-arrow">
                <title>cheveron down</title>
                <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="other" class="accordion-content list-reset leading-normal px-8 py-4 hidden">
        Here is some more content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the HTML you posted on sharepoint.stackexchange.  Hopefully it gets approved, because I couldn't have answered the question without it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `e.target` isn't what you think it is.  `e.target` is what the user clicked on, so if they click on the header, or the SVG, then e.target is the header or the SVG, not the title row you are expecting, so the comparison:

```
content.previousElementSibling === e.target
```

works very inconsistently.

To fix it, I wrote the following function, which will search backward to a parent containing the class `accordion-title-row`.

```
function getTitleRowFromChild(elem) {
    var result = elem;
    while(result && !result.classList.contains("accordion-title-row")) {
        if(result.parentElement)
            result = result.parentElement;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then I modified toggleAccordion like so:

```
function toggleAccordion(e) {
    // get the title row from the target
    var titleRow = getTitleRowFromChild(e.target);

    accordionContentPanes.forEach(function(content) {

        // change comparison to title row instead of e.target
        if (content.previousElementSibling === titleRow) {
            // this block is the only change
            if(content.classList.contains("hidden")) {
                removeClass(content, "hidden");
                addClass(content.parentElement, "active");                
            }
            else {
                removeClass(content.parentElement, "active");
                addClass(content, 'hidden');
            }
        } else {
            removeClass(content.parentElement, "active");
            addClass(content, 'hidden');

        }
    });
}
```

After which the accordion works as expected.  Full example up on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmcshea/Lvjyunwd/), which includes HTML I got from your sharepoint.stackexchange post.  It doesn't have all of your styles of course, but the accordion works.

Comment: Thanks @JoeMcShea, I see it toggles but I also want the open content to close when you click on its own title row, as it is now the content keeps showing when you click on it.

Comment: That's only a small adjustment.  I've updated the code above and the fiddle with that behavior.  Starts with `// this block is the only change`.

Comment: I appreciate your time and knowledge this works smoothly. Can I ask you another question in reference to another code I am developing but I am stuck with? It has to do with the accordion's content

Comment: If this worked for you, you should mark it as the answer. As for the other question, you should post it here as a new question, with enough detail that it can be answered, and if I can help I will. It appears that my edit was rejected, and without the HTML this question couldn't have been answered, so you might want to edit the question and add the HTML yourself.

Comment: I tried to add the HTML and it was rejected as well. Thanks for your help!